# Array asociativo accesible sin saber el nombre de la clave

Tags: php, array

En mi serie de escribir un buscador, estoy con el método `mostrar_resultados` que debe ser un código genérico y tengo el código que muestro mas abajo y funciona correctamente. La cuestión es que las claves no siempre van a ser `'id'`, `'razon_social'` y `'nombre_comercial'`. Depende de si se busca en clientes, proveedores, presupuestos, etc., y necesito alguna forma de acceder a las claves sin saber cuál es el nombre de la clave. Estuve leyendo la documentación de PHP sobre [`current()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php). Entiendo la lógica de la operación sin embargo no logro visualizarla en mi código.

```
    ...mas código...
    foreach($datos_arr as $clave => $valor) {
    
                $salida .= sprintf($linea_tabla, $valor['id'], $valor['razon_social'], $valor['nombre_comercial']);
    
                if (($clave % 2) == 0) {
                    $salida = str_replace("##", " color_linea", $salida);
                } else { $salida = str_replace("##", "", $salida); }
            }
    ... mas código ...
```

`$datos_arr` es el resultado de un `json_decode()` (es un array válido).
`$linea_tabla` es la plantilla de cada línea de la tabla.

Graceas!

Comment: aahh! podría meter un `foreach($valor as $clave2 => $valor2)`, no? Y acceder a `$valor2` y debería armar un array y pasarselo al `sprintf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
        foreach($datos_arr as $clave => $valor) {
            $sprintefe_args = array();
            foreach($valor as $clave2 => $valor2) {
                $sprintefe_args[] = $valor2;
            }
            $salida .= sprintf($linea_tabla, $sprintefe_args[0], $sprintefe_args[1], $sprintefe_args[2]);
//          $salida .= sprintf($linea_tabla, $valor['id'], $valor['razon_social'], $valor['nombre_comercial']);


            if (($clave % 2) == 0) {
                $salida = str_replace("##", " color_linea", $salida);
            } else { $salida = str_replace("##", "", $salida); }
        }
```

La variable `sprintefe` contiene los valores de `valor` sin la clave. Luego en el `sprintf()` los asocio vía numérica en la cadena de referencia `$linea_tabla`.